# How can I ensure that code works the same way in strict mode and lax mode?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, strict

I'm starting a new javascript application and would like to use strict mode. However, we will still have to support some older browsers (IE8,9) that don't support strict mode. Some of my co-workers are worried about the runtime semantics changes that come with strict mode -- they are concerned that strict functions will behave differently when run in lax mode on old browsers.

**Is there a set of additional restrictions I can add to make sure that functions have the same runtime semantics under lax mode as strict mode?** Specifically, I want a set of rules I can check with an automated, lint-like tool. My first thought is to prevent people from using `eval` or `arguments`. Would that be enough?

Would coding in coffeescript help to accomplish this?

---

For example, consider the following function:

```
(function(){
 'use strict';

 function foo(bar) {
    arguments[0] = 'You are in lax mode';
    alert(bar);
 }
 foo('You are in strict mode');
 })();
```

This function runs correctly in strict mode, but has different behaviour in lax mode. I'm looking for a set of rules that will make sure people can't accidentally do this.

Comment: I removed my answer because it was not what you are looking for. But I'm still unsure of what you want. Considering your example, do you want a rule like "don't assign to an `arguments` index and expect the correspondent named argument to change too" (which is difficult, maybe impossible to automate)? You seem to be okay with ruling out using `eval` and `arguments` entirely, but I'm afraid that might be too restrictive.

Comment: What I want is a set of rules I can check with an automated tool. So "don't use eval or arguments" is a reasonable rule, while "don't expect arguments to change" is not. I want a subset I can check statically, which ensures that I won't accidentally write code that triggers differences in dynamic behavior.

Comment: This is not a trivial undertaking, there is a summary of strict mode differences here; many of which you would not be able to detect with a linter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode

Comment: I understand it's not trivial; That's why I'm wondering if someone's done it -- so I don't have to. I'm now seeing people recommend against strict mode because it will behave differently in IE<9; I'm looking for a "stricter mode" to prevent that from being a viable argument.

Comment: I believe having an IDE that force quality standards and allows you to customize them based on your project/requirements would definitely help you out. Are you looking for such options?

Comment: @SeanMcMillan I'm not sure if my answer does really answer your question, or if you just awarded the bounty for lack of other options. If you want, I can set a new bounty on your question.

Comment: @bfavaretto: You're very kind. Your answer was the only one that dug into what the semantic differences between strict and lax mode are, so that was helpful. While a harsh limit like "don't use `arguments` or `eval`" might get me most of the way to what I want, avoiding the shifts around `this` would require throwing the baby out with the bathwater. I gave you the bounty because it's the best answer today, but I think that there isn't really going to be a better answer in the future. I'll just have to fight the battle the hard way.

Answer (score 3):

All the strict mode features are summarized in the [Annex C](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-C) of the the ECMAScript specification. In most cases, strict mode will throw errors when you try to use disallowed features (new reserved words, octal literals and escape sequences, multiple definition of the same property in an object literal, etc.). I understand your question is about the cases that won't throw any errors, so here they are:

> - Arguments objects for strict mode functions do not dynamically share their array indexed property values with the corresponding formal parameter bindings of their functions. (10.6).
> - For strict mode functions, if an arguments object is created the binding of the local identifier arguments to the arguments object is immutable and hence may not be the target of an assignment expression. (10.5).

This causes the problem seen in the example you have. If you are disallowing the use of `arguments` entirely, you won't have any problems here. I personally believe that disallowing the use of `arguments` is too radical, but that's your call.

> - Strict mode eval code cannot instantiate variables or functions in the variable environment of the caller to eval. Instead, a new variable environment is created and that environment is used for declaration binding instantiation for the eval code (10.4.2).

You're also disallowing `eval`, so you're fine here too.

> If `this` is evaluated within strict mode code, then the `this` value is not coerced to an object. A `this` value of `null` or `undefined` is not converted to the global object and primitive values are not converted to wrapper objects. The `this` value passed via a function call (including calls made using `Function.prototype.apply` and `Function.prototype.call`) do not coerce the passed this value to an object (10.4.3, 11.1.1, 15.3.4.3, 15.3.4.4).

This one means two things:

1. `this` will not be coerced to the global object in case it's undefined, so:

   ```
   //"use strict";
   function foo() {
       console.log(this); 
   }
   foo();
   // logs undefined in strict mode, and window in classic mode
   ```

   I don't think this one can be caught with static analysis. It might cause an error in strict mode depending on what you want to do with `this`. For example, inside the function `this.foo = 'bar'` will create a global variable in classic mode, but raise a TypeError in classic mode. But `typeof this` won't throw any errors, only yield different results.
2. `this` will not be coerced to a wrapper object when it's set as a primitive value. For example:

   ```
   //"use strict";
   function valtype() { return typeof this }
   console.log(valtype.call("foo"));
   // logs "string" in strict mode and "object" in classic mode
   ```

   This one doesn't sound like a big deal, but may cause problems. I also think this cannot be detected with static analysis.

Bottom line: imposing restrictions and creating a lint tool for this might not be the best solution. It may not even be possible. Why don't you create a set of unit tests instead?

Comment: Good question, @sreservoir. I have no idea what I had in mind back when I wrote that. Edited to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second part of your question:

> Would coding in coffeescript help to accomplish this?

Yes and no. The example you gave is related to semantics (as most strict mode things are). Coffeescript changes the syntax but leaves the semantics the same.

[Coffeescript issue #1547](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1547) discusses some functionality for syntax checking that coffeescript *does* support.

Additionally there are some cases not discussed in that issue that CS implicitly solves:

- Accidental global variables: *global variables can only be formed explicitly by attaching them to `window`*
- The `with` block: *it simply doesn't have any way of forming such a block*
- Issues with `arguments` *are [largely mitigated with splats](http://coffeescript.org/#splats)*

Coffeescript helps a bit, but it isn't a cure. You can still shoot yourself in the foot with it, but it does try to force you to be a bit more explicit about doing so.

I should point out that most of the stuff Coffeescript saves you from are the same problems JSHint and JSLint try to solve. You may want to simply use one of those instead of moving to another language.

Comment: So, coffeescript + "use splats instead of arguments" takes care of one piece. That's nice. JS{LH}int seems to focus more on style than on semantics.

Answer (score -1):

I think your best bet is to just test your code on a browser with strict mode. It is the only way to provide real results.

Comment: Of course we should, and we will. But right now people are arguing _against_ strict mode on the grounds that we need to support IE8, and it might behave differently there. I want to turn "might" into "won't".

Comment: Can't you just test with IE8?

Comment: @dandavis: I'd like to know what those are.

Comment: @user2297366: Sure, and we will, but the goal is to close a hole in reasoning about how code will behave. "More testing" does not cover the semantic inference.

Comment: Oh. You are still in the development stage. Thanks for the info. In that case, visit [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/br230269(v=vs.94).aspx) to check out the differences with strict mode.